# Mongo Design question with Rails/Mongoid for a bill tracking app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, activemodel

I'm writing a quick app for a user to track their daily bills (for money tracking purposes).  I want the user to be able to define their own categories that a bill can be applicable for.  I'm trying however to decide the best way to model this and also validate categories as unique.

My initial thought was this:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :bills

  field :categories, :type => Array
end

class Bill
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeded_in :user, :inverse_of => :bills

  field :category
  index :category
end
```

So a user can add categories, just as strings, and when they add a bill, they'll choose from their available categories for the bill.

So, a couple questions:

1. Does this seem like the proper design?  I Don't think it's necessary to define an actual category model as it's literally just a string used to index bills on, but I'm not sure if there are other benefits to a separate model
2. How do I validate_uniqueness_of :categories in my user model.  I don't think it works on array items like this, but I could be wrong.  I don't want a user to create  categories with the same name.  I suppose this might be the advantage of a separate model, embedded in the User, but again it seems like more work than necessary.

Can someone tell me my best options here to validate that a user has unique categories (but users can have the same categories, i obviously don't care about that, just unique in the scope of a single user)

Answer (score 1):

**[Update]**

The design seems proper. In a Rails specific way how would you validate the uniqueness? When adding a category pull the list and do an `indexOf` check to ensure it doesn't exist. If it does just bounce back an error.

I'm not a Rails guy, let me know if I'm off track or something.

---

I'm not sure MongoDB would be the best choice of storage engines for that. You would be better off using MySQL with a categories table.

Knocks against MongoDB:

- Not ACID transactions
- No single server durability
- Not relational (you want relational for a bill tracking application)

Comment: this is more of an exercise for fun, i'm not writing an enterprise app or anything, i just wanted to learn mongo with rails3 and thought a quick little app like this would be a fun exercise

Comment: @brad: I'm not a Rails guy, but I would be to store categories inline in an array under the user object. Let me update my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i should have mentioned that I obviously know how to do this manually with an `indexOf` or `include?`, just wasn't sure if there was a more railsy way to do this.  I may end up selecting this answer though since it does technically answer my Q, will just wait a bit.

Comment: @Brad: I mean pull the object and check if that object exists in Ruby not Mongo.